# How to redirect an Angular2 application with javascript, using router and aux outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have this link

`<a [routerLink]="['/path1', { outlets: { 'scope': ['scope1'] } }]" routerLinkActive="active">link</a>`

I want to recreate the action of clicking it, in a javascript script that I append to my component. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using javascript as the angular language?

Comment: @AlexN. No, I'm using typescript. I'm attaching a javascript script to my angular component.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event on the click on your link, and then bind this event to a method in your component that will navigate using an instance of the router from DI.

Example (without parameters, just the action) :

**Template :**

```
<a (click)="navigate()">link</a>
```

**Component :**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

...

constructor(private router: Router) { }

navigate() {
   this.router.navigate(['/path1']);
}
```

N.B : The syntax might change a bit depending on your `@angular/router` version, make sure you are using the latest version.